# Web Push API: title and body max length and how to delete push notification

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, web-push

I'm trying to figure out the max title and body length for desktop push notification to Chrome and Firefox.

and is it possible to delete a notification that wasn't delivered using the message_id attribute?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> the max title and body length for desktop push notification

Currently the standard doesn't say anything about the max length. If the notification title or body is too long for a given device, it gets truncated when the notification is displayed.

> is it possible to delete a notification that wasn't delivered using the message_id attribute?

What are you referring to? `message_id` is probably something specific for FCM or some other service (it's not part of the standard).

In general the Push API allows you to replace a notification by using [the `tag` option](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerRegistration/showNotification).

Comment: Got it thanks!
So no way to delete unneeded message?

Comment: @johndepp usually when you send push notifications you don't delete them... the user can dismiss them on its device without your intervention. You may want to consider a TTL for notifications in order to avoid the delivery of old unneeded messages.